# How do I change the destination of copying a line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to make a time tracker that automatically recognizes when someone enters a line and copies it into another worksheet. That works quite well in itself at the moment by doing it as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e) {
  
  var startRow = 6;  // Start Row
  var targetColumn = 3; // Start Column
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2"; // Worksheet from which the data is to be copied
  var row = e.range.getRow(); // Position of the row in which the time is saved
  var col = e.range.getColumn();  
  

  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws && col != "") {
    // In this section the times are set
    var currentDate = new Date(); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(row, 4).setValue(currentDate); // Put the current date in the 4 column (Carried Out)
    if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(row, 3).getValue() == "") {
      // If the "registered" cell is "empty", the new date is set to the 3rd column
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(row, 3).setValue(currentDate);
    }
  }

  // Copy Value of the Row 
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
   
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var val = cell.getValue();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(row, 1).setValue(val);
  }
}
```

My problem is that the whole thing should work continuously, as an example row C3 is occupied and this person is unsubscribing, now someone new is entering and his starting time is saved in a new column in the other worksheet. So that at the end of the day I can see who was entered in C3 for how long. I hope the whole thing was halfway understandable.

I understand your answer iansedano, but I have trouble implementing it. I've tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work at all. In addition, I always get the error "Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined".

```
function addTimestamp(e) {
  
  var startRow = sourceSheet.getRange(3, 6, 1, 10);  // Start Row
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2"; // Worksheet from which the data is to be copied
  var row = targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 10);
  var row2 = targetSheet.getRange(4, 2, 1, 10); // Position of the row in which the time is saved
  //var col = e.range.getColumn();  
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1")
  
  if(sourceSheet === ws && startRow != "") {
    // In this section the times are set
    var currentDate = new Date(); 
    row.setValue(currentDate); // Put the current date in the 4 column (Carried Out)
    if(targetSheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue() == "") {
      // If the "registered" cell is "empty", the new date is set to the 3rd column
      row2.setValue(currentDate);
    }
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd)
  }

  /* Copy Value of the Row 
  if(targetSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
   
    var cell = sourceSheet;
    var val = cell.getRange(row, 1).getValues();
    var test = "Value 1";
    let rowToAdd = [test, "", "", "Value 4"]
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd)
  }*/
  
}
```

Comment: So what's the question, how to make it run on every change?

Comment: The question is how can I make the time automatically saved in the next line?

Comment: Do you mean, how make sure that you don't overwrite the previous line?

Comment: yes exactly sorry if that was a bit incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use [AppendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Find a way to construct the whole row in this format

```js
let rowToAdd = ["Value 1", "", "", "Value 2"]
```

Where the `""` are just blank values. Instead of using `getRange()` and `getValue()` multiple times. You should get the whole row

```
getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues()
```

This will get the row from column 1 to 10 and return the values in a 2D array like this:

```
[
    ["1", "2", "3"] 
]
```

Then do your tests on it and modify it as you need, once you have your range as a 1D array, then call it like this:

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd)
```

#### Some advice

Also I would try to define more variables to make your code easier to manage and maintain, for instance, your code above could be re-written like this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e) {
  
  var startRow = 6;  // Start Row
  var targetColumn = 3; // Start Column
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2"; // Worksheet from which the data is to be copied
  var row = e.range.getRow(); // Position of the row in which the time is saved
  var col = e.range.getColumn();  
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1")
  
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && sourceSheet === ws && col != "") {
    // In this section the times are set
    var currentDate = new Date(); 
    targetSheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(currentDate); // Put the current date in the 4 column (Carried Out)
    if(targetSheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue() == "") {
      // If the "registered" cell is "empty", the new date is set to the 3rd column
      targetSheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(currentDate);
    }
  }

  // Copy Value of the Row 
  if(targetSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
   
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var val = cell.getValue();
    targetSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(val);
  }
}
```

#### Reference

- [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)